# Linear Discriminant Analysis Algorithm

Tags: image-processing

I  have started to learn image processing and I am trying to learn LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis)  algorithm. I want to ask a question to understand the philosophy of LDA. If it is is useful to use LDA in the distribution in the first example, is it also useful to use LDA in the distribution in the second example. I mean if I rotate 90 degrees to the image, is LDA still useful?

first
[image: first]

second
[image: second]

Comment: Yes, of course. I’m confused as to why you ask this question? Any reason you think this would not be the case?

Comment: @CrisLuengo can you explain briefly for me, please?

Answer (score 0):

LDA is a generative algorithm that allows to classify predictors in two or more classes divided by **linear boundaries**. So, if you **rotate** the image the LDA algorithm does not lose its value, as long as you fit two different LDA models.